# Set Div Width to 20% of Page Width Without Margins

Tags: html, css

[image: Screenshot]

I have this menu page that I want to split into 5 equal columns.

My current CSS for the yellow divs is:

```
width:20%;
height:100vh;
background-color: yellow;
display:inline-block;
```

Above this, I also have `margin:0;`. How can I remove the small white gap between the yellow blocks?

Comment: we need to see an example, like one set up in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) - we need to see the HTML as well as all the css for the elements displayed

Comment: In general, how should I make it so that the 5 divs are perfectly aligned in a row without margins?

Comment: there are several ways, plus also it could be some specific anomaly in your code, by seeing the code we can suggest the best solution for your case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using display inline-block has the weird sideeffect that it creates unwanted gaps between elements: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

A quick fix would be to float the div's left instead of using display: inline-block.

```css
div {
    width:20%;
    height:100vh;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>Monday</div>
<div>Tuesday</div>
<div>Wednesday</div>
<div>Thursday</div>
<div>Friday</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I never knew this! (It worked) :D

Comment: Glad this fixed it for you :)